# multivariable calculus/ divergence thm. what's wrong with my calculation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

the question asks:

Use the Divergence Theorem to calculate the surface integral $
\iint \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}$; that is, calculate the flux of $\mathbf{F}$ across S.
$\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)=e^xsiny\mathbf{i}+e^x cosy\mathbf{j}+yz^2\mathbf{k}$, S is the surface of the box bounded by the planes x = 0, x=1,y=0,y=1,z=0,and z=2.

my working as follows:

$\iint \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S} = \iiint\limits_E div\mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{V} 
= \iiint\limits_E (e^x-e^xsin(y)+2yz) d\mathbf{V}$

for the region $E= \{0\le x\le1, 0\le y\le1,0\le z\le2\}$

$\int_{0}^{2} \!\! \int_{0}^{1} \!\! \int_{0}^{1} \!  (e^x-e^xsin(y)+2yz) d\ x \, d\ y \, d\ z = 2+2(e-1)cos(1)$

the correct answer is 2, could you please  point out where I made the mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: where did $\sin y$ go in the x-term? You should get divergence as $2yz$, rest cancel out.

Comment: "$\sin y$" is constant when differentiating with respect to $x$, so it moves through the derivative like any other constant multiple.

Comment: thanks, you guys are right.